# Tool exits with message "Exiting with return code: -1"

Tags: azure, service, devops

I have ran the tool and it executes perfectly like how it is. At the end of migration I get the below message "Exiting with return code: 0".

Normally, I wouldnt bother. However, I am implementing the migration using Azure DevOps release pipelines.
With this message the deployment stage always fails.

Does someone has any idea about this error

```
The last few lines of execution
Migration Processor Complete TfsTeamSettingsProcessor
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4698310Z [07:12:23 INF] TfsTeamSettingsProcessor completed in 00:00:02.9601088
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4746613Z [07:12:23 INF] Application is shutting down...
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4787008Z [07:12:23 DBG] Hosting stopping
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4792590Z [07:12:23 DBG] Exiting with return code: 0
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4797995Z [07:12:23 INF] Terminating: Application forcebly closed.
2021-04-23T07:12:23.4802683Z [07:12:23 INF] Application Ending
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like robocopy exit codes 0-7 indicate success. I changed from command line execution to powershell command and added this to the bottom of your script:

if ($lastexitcode -lt 8) { $lastexitcode = 0 }

This works for me.